# How does Intent work?

Tags: android, android-intent

When I say,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, TestActivity.class);
```

The question is whether a new instance of TestActivity is created every time intent is instantiated. Or does it use a singleton copy?

I looked into a few documentations and hardly managed to find an answer. What do you think about this?

Answer (score 3):

it depends which flags you use when you start a new activity. if you use FLAG_REORDER_TO_TOP, it will take an old instance and put on top of the activity stack. if you don't specify anything, a new instance will be created and started